# Receiving Compiler Errors for a Undeclared Class and then a Duplicate Class

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

I have just created a program which creates an array of Card Objects, Shuffles them, and Prints them. But i'm getting the following errors and as a student, i'm having trouble understanding why.

Errors:

> "HW6GetBig.java:23: error: class Card is public, should be declared in
>   a file named Card.java public class Card {"
>
> "HW6GetBig.java:39: error: class DeckOfCards is public, should be
>   declared in a file named DeckOfCards.java public class DeckOfCards {"
>
> "HW6GetBig.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>           DeckOfCards myDeckofCards = new DeckofCards();"

As hitherto, i'm stuck and not sure why the Class is coming up as undeclared. If i change the file name to Card in netbeans i'm still getting an error stating a duplicate class has been found. Please help.

Thank you very much,
                     - Synergy

```
 class HW6GetBig
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            DeckOfCards myDeckofCards = new DeckofCards();
            myDeckofCards.deckShuffler(); // Randomizes / Shuffles the Cards in the Deck, using a Random # and Swaps

            // Print 52 Cards in the Order in which they are dealt
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
                // Deal and Print 4 Cards
                System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n",
                myDeckofCards.dealCard(), myDeckofCards.dealCard(),
                myDeckofCards.dealCard(), myDeckofCards.dealCard());
            }
        }
    }
    public class Card {
        //Card Class represents a Virtual Playing Card in our Deck
        private String rank; // Ranks Of Card
        private String suit; // Suit Of Card

        // Two Argument Constructor initializes card's face and suit
        public Card(String cardRank, String cardSuit) {
            rank = cardRank; // Intializing Values of Card's Rank
            suit = cardSuit; // Intializing Values of Card's Suit
        }
        // Return String representing the Card
        public String CardToString() {
            return rank + " of " + suit;
        }

    }
    public class DeckOfCards {
        private Card deck[]; //Declaration of Array of Card Objects
        private int topCard; //Card to be Dealt
        private final int NUM_CARDS = 52; // Constant # Of Cards in a Standard Deck
        int random = (int)(Math.random()*52+1);

        public DeckOfCards() {
            String ranks[] = {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven",
            "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
            String suits[] = {"Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"};

            deck = new Card[NUM_CARDS]; // Creating an Array of Card Objects
            topCard = 0; // Setting Current Card so 1st Card is deck[0]
            // Filling the Seats of our Empty Deck Room with Card Objects
            for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
                deck[i] = new Card(ranks[i % 13], suits[i / 13]);
                // End of Deck Of Cards Constructor
            }
        }
            public void deckShuffler() {
                // After Shuffling, The Deck should begin at deck[0] once again
                topCard = 0;
                // For each Card, pick a "Random Card/#" and Swap.
                for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
                    // Obtaining a Random # Between 0 and 51.
                    int j = random;
                    // Swapping Currently Selected Card (i) with Random Card (j)
                    Card tempObject = deck[i];
                    deck[i] = deck[j];
                    deck[j] = tempObject;
                }
            }
                public Card dealCard() {
                    // Ensure the Top Card does not exceed the Deck Length
                    if (topCard < deck.length) {
                    return deck[topCard++];
                    } else {
                    return null;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages say it all:

> class Card is public, should be declared in a file named Card.java
>   class DeckOfCards is public, should be declared in a file named
>   DeckOfCards.java

These are your options:

- Move both of these classes to their own file, as suggested in the error messages.
- Remove the `public` modifier from the class declarations.

See the relevant section in the Java Language Specification, [7.6. Top Level Type Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host
>   system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time
>   error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the
>   type name plus an extension (such as `.java` or `.jav`) if either of the
>   following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared `public` (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).

Comment: Thank you so much! You made the problem much more obvious to me with a straight answer, my code is working now. Really appreciate the help!